# Regular expressions+python challenge! Wrangling data that's almost-regular

Tags: python, regex

I'm sorry to be posting this, but I've killed a lot of time working on this unsuccessfully. So, a regular expressions+Python challenge for one and all:

I'm working with data that's mostly regularly formatted. Lists of companies are combined into a string like

```
`Company Inc,Company, LLC,Company`
```

without quotes to delineate the entries. Using the regular, above example, I can do:

```
>>> re.split(r',\b', 'Company Inc,Company, LLC,Company')                                                                                                                                                                                    
['Company Inc', 'Company, LLC', 'Company']
```

Unfortunately, some strings are irregularly-formatted like:

```
`IBP, Inc,Tyson Foods,Inc.`
```

wherein `,Inc` is not separated from `Foods` by a space. So, using `r',\b'`, I get this:

```
>>> re.split(r',\b', 'IBP, Inc,Tyson Foods,Inc.')
['IBP, Inc', 'Tyson Foods', 'Inc.']
```

I would like to get this:

```
['IBP, Inc', 'Tyson Foods,Inc.']
```

What would you do in this situation?

Comment: use ms excel to wrangle it

Comment: Your rules aren't clearly defined - this isn't possible. How should `Inc.,LLC,Inc.` parse? `'Inc.','LLC','Inc.'`? `'Inc.,LLC','Inc.'`? `'Inc.', 'LLC,Inc.'`? You're using human intuition and experience to split these names. Until you can express your intuition as a series of rules, a regex won't help you.

Comment: Honestly?  I'd probably split the whole thing by commas and then merge the special cases of `Inc[.]`, `LLC`, and so on back in, assuming that it's always `Company Name [,] SomethingSpecial`. You want `c,Comp` to split on the comma but `s,Inc` not to, and I can't see how that's going to happen without special-casing.  Might as well be explicit about it.

Comment: Go through your data and search for any `,Inc` or `,LLC` and other special cases, then replace with `, Inc` and `, LLC`, respectively. Afterwards use your regex.

Comment: The question is how did list of companies get combined into such a string?  I'd go back and get the data in a better format.

Comment: @nathanhayfield: that would would be my first mistake. Excel is an oft-misapplied, terrible tool.

Comment: @Eric: I know what you mean but that's what I'm doing here actually. I am working to "express my intuition as a set of rules".

Comment: @Gerrat: Now, what kind of advice is that? Why would you suggest that? Why would you think I can go back and get the data in a better format?  If I could, would I be posting here?

Comment: @DSM: Thanks. I was thinking about this too. Michael Scott Cuthbert suggests this below, as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If known, you could add the split-prevention strings to a negative lookahead

```
r',\b(?!Inc\.)'
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Now I need to look up this syntax to get a handle on how it works!

Comment: But yeah, thanks again for answering this question. This is just what I was looking for. Sooo many people either dwelled on the open-endedness of my question (though I tried to ask it in a way to get the response you provided) or tried telling me not to use Regular Expressions at all. In addition to Excel, some people tried to point me to things like Parsley (a parser), etc. I appreciate your seeing my question as I tried to pose it and your providing the response I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

To put Mike M's response in slightly different terms, if you can build a reliable list of non-relevant tokens like 'Inc.', 'Inc' and 'LLC', then you might have a way to parse. Even then, you're probably not going to get something automatic like split() to work for you. You'll probably have to roll your own.

Comment: Yeah, scary. To be honest, I would prefer bad splits to complexity in this part of the program. When it comes to this type of code, I'm not a good programmer, so rolling my own parsing mumbo jumbo would quickly get out of hand.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a first split on the comma to get lists such as:

```
['IBP', 'Inc', 'Tyson Foods', 'Inc.']
```

and then do a second pass through the data where highly improbable company names such as 'Inc', 'Inc.', 'LLC', 'GmbH', etc. get combined with the previous entry in the list:

```
badList = originalData.split(',')
goodList = []
rejectList = ['Inc', 'Inc.', 'LLC', 'GmbH'] # etc.

for pseudoName in badList:
   pseudoName = pseudoName.strip()
   if pseudoName in rejectList:
      goodList[-1] = goodList[-1] + ", " + pseudoName
   else:
      goodList.append(pseudoName)
```

This method would also let you do more sophisticated manipulations if you later find that your data has entries such as "Farmers Group, The" and put the articles in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the number of entries you have to figure out. Basically, as far as high-quality data goes, you're screwed. That means any automation you try to apply will have problems dealing with your data.

You're going to have to fix this by hand to put data quality back into it. Data quality issues are one of those things that computers have a very hard time dealing with.

What I personally would do is to write a quick-and-dirty heuristic to try to determine entries that don't fit the expected results. For instance, in your example, I would look for split entries that are "Inc" or "LLC" plus or minus a couple of characters. That would catch entries which seem to not provide much above a corporation type. You would catch the "Inc." and know that the *real* corporation name must be nearby.

Once you have that, you can clean your data, by hand, and reprocess. This is the best bet up to a gajillion entries or so, when you can justify writing these sort of corrective actions as a part of your program. Unless you're Google, though, it's almost guaranteed that you'll find it quickest and easiest to put human eyes on it.